# PHP find array key in two dimension array

Tags: php, search, find, key, multidimensional-array

```
<?php
$x = array(
       "C_Card_ID" => array(
                              "dbName"=>"CardID",
                              "type"=>"disabled",
                              "key"=>"primary"
                          ),
       "C_Payroll_ID" => array(
                              "dbName"=> "PayrollID",
                              "key"=>"unique"
                          ),
       "C_First_Name" => array("dbName"=>"FirstName")
?>
```

I want keys of `$x` which has `"key"` index in its second array. In simple words, i need C_Card_ID and C_Payroll_ID as an output in array, so later i will implode them.

```
Required output Sample : Array("C_Card_ID","C_Payroll_ID")
```

**Please don't use Loop algo. I need to use some build-in function.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`array_filter`](http://php.net/array_filter):

syntax is:

```
$filtered_array = array_keys(array_filter($x, function($a){ return isset($a['key']); }));
```

Answer (score 2):

This should do:

```
$result = array_keys(array_filter($x, function($arr){
  return array_key_exists('key', $arr);
}));
```

Comment: Warning: array_key_exists() expects parameter 2 to be array, string given in xx.php on line xx

Comment: instead of array_key_exists('key', $arr); .... isset($arr['key']) work fine for all string and array. nice answer, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try to use [array_slice()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) like,

```
<?php
    $x = array(
           "C_Card_ID" => array(
                                  "dbName"=>"CardID",
                                  "type"=>"disabled","key"=>"primary"
                              ),
           "C_Payroll_ID" => array(
                                  "dbName"=> "PayrollID",
                                  "key"=>"unique"
                              ),
           "C_First_Name" => array("dbName"=>"FirstName"));
    print_r(array_slice(array_keys($x),0,2));
    //Outputs
    //Array ( [0] => C_Card_ID [1] => C_Payroll_ID ) 
?>
```

**Tested on** http://writecodeonline.com/php/

Comment: correct but i am using associative array and my indexing is not fixed at 0,1 or 2 etc. however helpful